# Postgres error with Rails - I'm running locally but the database won't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently trying to install to run Catarse on my Mac (Yosemite)

When I try and run `rake db:create db:migrate db:seed` I get the following message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:  role "admin" already exists
:     CREATE ROLE admin NOLOGIN;
    -- This script assumes a role postgrest and a role anonymous already created
GRANT usage ON SCHEMA postgrest TO admin;
GRANT usage ON SCHEMA "1" TO admin;
GRANT select, insert ON postgrest.auth TO admin;
GRANT select ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "1" TO admin;
GRANT admin TO postgrest;
```

I have tried to do the above but to no avail, and now it's saying that I have a duplicate admin role. Can anybody please offer some guidance or assistance?

I've spent most of the day troubleshooting and looking at this over and over again in frustration by doing the following:

Uninstalling catarse
Reinstalling and uninstalling postgresql
Trying to implement the above `GRANT` commands

Comment: A suggestion: use this http://postgresapp.com/

Comment: I have been using the postgreapp with the command line (open psql) but to no avail.  It is where I have entered the GRANT commands.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have given unique constraint for the role name in the database level. So please verify whether the column has the uniq index or there is unique validation given in the Role model class and you have not given ! symbol while trying to save the role. I think its not a good practice to give the constraints in the database level and its better to specify everything in the model level itself. Otherwise there will be database service exceptions itself which may not be getting caught in the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exceptions.

Comment: which column would that be?